# syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE)

Tags: php, mysql

Codigo con el error:

```
if(!empty($_GET['horarios'])){
        $cod_hor=$_GET['horarios'];
    }else{
        header('Location:error.php');
    }

    if($_SESSION['tipo_pro']=='a' or $_SESSION['tipo_pro']=='p'){
        $profesor=$_SESSION['ced_pro'];

        $pa=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE ced_pro='$profesor' and cod_hor='$cod_hor'");             
        if($row=mysql_fetch_array($pa)){
            $oNivel=new Consultar_Nivel($row['cod_niv']);
            $nombre_horario=$oNivel->consultar('nivel').'.'.$row['horario'];
          }else{
            header('Location:error.php');

      }else{
    header('Location:error.php');
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diría que el problema principal es que no indentas tu código. Y como resultado, es muy fácil omitir un `{` o `}` en alguna parte.

En este caso en particular, la siguiente combinación de sentencias es incorrecta:

```
    }else{
      header('Location:error.php');

}else{
```

Es equivalente a:

```
if (...) {
} else {
} else { /* el segundo else es ilegal */
}
```

.. no puedes definir 2 `else` en un condición.

Nuevamente, debido a que no tienes buena indentación de tu código, es díficil saber exactamente cual era tu intención. Pero asumo que necesitas un `}` entre los 2 `else`:

```
    }else{
      header('Location:error.php');
    } /* tal vez te faltó esto aquí */
}else{
```